# Modify an opened word document through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How can I modify an opened word document through Excel with VBA?
Here a bit of code I'm writing, but there's something wrong I can't understand.

```
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
'ThisWorkbook is the opened Excel Workbook through which I control Word documents.

If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")) <> 0 then 
         'if the document exists in the folder where ThisWorkbook is saved, I check
         'if the document is already opened.

   If IsFileOpened(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx") 
         'if during the run-time I get here, it means that the document exists and 
         'it's already opened.
         'Now I want to get the reference to the opened document "Report.docx",
         'so I do a thing like this.

         Set WordDoc= Word.Application.Documents(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")

         'When it tries to excute the instruction over, it gives me a message in which
         'it is written that the name is bad or inexistent, even if the document
         'is already opened. Is the instruction correct?

         Set WordApp= WordDoc.Application
         '...other code

   Else
         'if the document isn't opened, I open it.
      Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx") 
         '..other code
   End If

Else     'I create a new document called "Report.docx" if it doesn't exist 
         'in the folder where ThisWorkbook is saved.
   Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add("Report.docx")
   '.... other code 
End If
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: On which line does it break?

Comment: in this...

Set WordDoc= Word.Application.Documents(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")

Comment: I assume you've added Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library to your references? Have you tried eliminating the file path from Set WordDoc= Word.Application.Documents(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")?

Comment: I think yes, otherwise you'd get a problem on "Dim WordDoc As Word.Document" when trying to run it. I don't know why it breaks there. I've got another way that works if you want though...

Comment: and your sub IsFileOpened actually works correctly? meaning your file is indeed open when it reaches the line where it breaks?

Comment: IsFileOpened works correctly and when it reaches the line where it breaks the document is opened. I get this run-time error: 4160- bad file name.
but, if there are any other ways that works, I'd like to know them.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this version

```
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx"
Set WordApp = GetObject(path).Application
```

in place of

```
Set WordDoc= Word.Application.Documents(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with an excel workbook and it worked

```
 Set WordDoc= Word.Application.Documents(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Report.docx")
```

should be

```
 Set WordDoc= Word.Documents("Report")
```

When I tried using the file path, I got Run-time error "9" Subscript out of range. When I used just the file name, it was successful.

Edit: After trying this with a word document, you do not need the application object and should not use the file extension. I can confirm that this works.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work the same.. I get this error:
Run-time error 4160 - bad file name.